# Select constructor through SFINAE in template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

I'm trying to select a constructor through SFINAE as following:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    template<typename C, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<C>::value>>
    MyClass(C) { }

    template<typename C, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<C>::value>>
    MyClass(C) { }
};
```

but the compiler complains with following error:

> error C2535: 'MyClass::MyClass(C)': member function already defined or declared

without even instantiating the constructor.

I worked out a working but ugly solution which i don't want to use because of the extra unused parameter:

```
template<typename T>
class MyWorkingClass
{
public:
    template<typename C>
    MyWorkingClass(C, std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<C>::value>* = nullptr) { }

    template<typename C>
    MyWorkingClass(C, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<C>::value>* = nullptr) { }
};
```

A short usage example is given here:

```
void* ptr = nullptr;
MyClass<int> mc1(ptr);

std::vector<int> vec;
MyClass<int> mc2(vec);

// Shall raise an error
// MyClass<int> mc2(0);
```

The traits `std::is_pointer` and `std::is_class` are just an example, the original traits are more complicated.

**Is there a way to select the constructor through SFINAE without adding another parameter to the constructor (maybe very close to the first appproach)?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the default values of arguments are not part of the template method signature.  So you have two `template<class C,class>ctor(c)` identical ctors.

```
template<class T>
struct MyClass {
  template<class C,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<C>{}>* =nullptr
  >
  MyClass(C) { }
  template<class C,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<C>{}>* =nullptr
  >
  MyClass(C) { }
};
```

here we use template value arguments of dependant type.  They never conflict, as the type of the pointer template argument is dependant on the type argument.

Answer (score 3):

Add one more (dummy) type template parameter:

```
template <typename C
        , typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<C>::value>>
MyClass(C) { }

template <typename C
        , typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<C>::value>
        , typename = void>
//        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
MyClass(C) { }
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a4c13d4d6a92cd2)

Answer (score 0):

This may be simplier:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    template<typename C, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<C>::value>>
    MyClass(C) { }

    template<typename C>
    MyClass(C*) { }
};
```

Not all of them need to be done by `std::enable_if_t`.